# LabVIEW VISA Read doesn't read data after system settings change

Tags: io, integer, labview, visa

I have greatly simplyfied my VI to the basic one below and it still doesn't work. I want to read the gain setting on my LakeShore 330 temperature controller. This is the way to do it and this is the way how it worked before changing some PC system settings. The buffer result should be an integer with a value between 000 and 999. In my case it should be 020 but shows 000, no matter what even if I change it to a different value in the controller. VISA Read still gives 000 as output.

[image]

I had some issues with system settings like delimiter, comma and dots for csv files. Basically my PC is now set to US standards instead of European and all my other software package work accordingly now. VISA Read still works fine with doubles etc coming from the controller but integers have all turned to 000.

Can anyone explain to me how VISA Read is affected by system settings, especially integers? I am quite confused because integers have no decimals, commas or other symbols.

Answer (score 1):

Open you Labview.ini file and look for the [LabVIEW] group and key useLocaleDecimalPt , if that's true it will use a period (.) as the decimal sign. Otherwise your local computer setting.
VISA will not deal with integers, as your example shows it will output a string.
But the code for your LakeShore 330 might have an incorrect formatter, is the VI code viewable? If so try to debug. [Here](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361J-01/lvconcepts/format_specifier_syntax/) is an overview of all the format specifier codes for [Format Into String](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361J-01/glang/format_into_string/). Especially the `%.;` (point), `%,;` (comma), `%;` (system default) codes.

Comment: I have no idea why but today LabVIEW decided to read the integer properly without any changes.... You are correct that VISA Read outputs a string and I guess the LakeShore 330 just outputs it as an ASCII string as well. But since the original layout of the number is an integer I was confused that it would not output properly. Anyway it works now, thank you for the aid.